# Git: в новой ветке удалил папку, теперь при merge в master она пропадает

Tags: git, git-merge, branch

Осваиваю git. Помогите разобраться в ситуации:

1) В мастер была папка А с файлами.

2) Создал новую ветку New из master.

3) Удалил в ветке New папку А и добвил паку Б с другими файлами.

4) Сделал несколько коммитов в ветку New (master не трогал).

5) Как итог: в master папка А с файлами, в New папка Б с другими файлами.

6) Теперь когда сливаю New в master (merge new), из мастер удаляется папка А (конфликтов не возникает). Если пробую «влить» master в New, то пишет, Already up to date.

**Вопрос: есть ли варианты объединить (merge) new и master сохранив обе папки с файлами.** Спасибо.

*PS
Это тестовый репозиторий. Работаю с ним один.*

Comment: пока решил вопрос git revert с указанием коммита где была удалена папка А

Comment: Мерж все коммиты из ветки пытается "накатить" на мастер. Так что удаление папки А считается полностью корректным действием. Да, поможет revert.

Comment: `git checkout 162448629e28^1 -- deleted_dir`, где `162448629e28` - коммит, где произошло удаление, `deleted_dir` - удаленный каталог. Затем закоммитить. В истории, конечно, будет сначала пропадание, а затем появление, как и в revert. Если важна история, то через `git rebase` (можно будет пофиксить удаление).

Comment: А зачем надо было удалять папку?